# How to run remote Jupyter notebook that can survive connection issues?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I use Jupyter notebook from my home computer to AWS EC2 that runs the Jupyter server. The connection is not 100% reliable and it would disconnect sometimes. Then the work on Jupyter notebook would stop.

Is there a configuration that can survive the connection issues? Ideally, I want the Jupyter server to continue to run and my web browser can reconnect to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure your server to run in the background. Check this post for more details:
[https://testnb.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Configuring the Notebook and Server.html](https://testnb.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Configuring%20the%20Notebook%20and%20Server.html)